# How to create a switch comparator in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is there a way to create a switch comparator like this one?

```
switch (item) {
    case (item<= 10):
        money += 25;
        $('#money').html(money);
        break;
    case (item > 10 && item <= 20):
        money += 50;
        $('#money').html(money);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be this:

```
 item = YourValue;
 switch (true) {

        case (item <= 10):
            money += 25;
            $('#money').html(money);
            break;
        case (item > 10 && item <= 20):
            money += 50;
            $('#money').html(money);
            break; 
     }
```

The expressions in the case statements will evaluate to true or false, and if that matches the switch condition,

but as per my suggestion you should go with if...else if...else statement for this kind of business logic.

Comment: Yes, that if and else if statements are better ;)

Comment: these kind of multi-conditional statement its better to use if...else if...else

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: No. Switch..case statements don't work like this. You would need an if & else if statement:

```
if (item <= 10)
{
    money += 25;
    $('#money').html(money);
}
else if (item > 10 && item <= 20)
{
    money += 50;
    $('#money').html(money);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `if else` instead of `switch`

```
if (item <= 10)
{
    money += 25;
    $('#money').html(money);
}
else if (item > 10 && item <= 20)
{
    money += 50;
    $('#money').html(money);
}
```

Comment: Just to make that clear, all of your answers were exacly correct, but I gave the 'right' answer to the first who answered, but thanks a lot anyway :)

Comment: Ahah to you too! @RahulTripathi